# materialize css custom error overlaps with other form fields

Tags: css, material-design, materialize, customvalidator

I was trying to style my form with Materialize CSS and there's something a little awkward with the data-success and data-error attributes, everything works fine but when the textbox wit error looses focus, the error message goes down and overlaps wit row of form elements as shown per image bellow: 
[image]

I have created a codepen as well to showcase the issue:

[codepen.io/anon/pen/KmvEZM](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmvEZM)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#icon_new_password, #icon_password_confirmation").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});

function checkPasswordMatch() {
  var password = $("#icon_new_password").val();
  var confirmPassword = $("#icon_password_confirmation").val();

  if (password != confirmPassword)
    $("#icon_new_password").attr("class", "invalid");
  $("label[for='icon_new_password']").attr("class", "active");
  $("#icon_password_confirmation").attr("class", "invalid");
  $("label[for='icon_password_confirmation']").attr("class", "active");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">vpn_key</i>
  <input id="icon_new_password" pattern=".{0}|^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$" type="password" class="validate" required>
  <label for="icon_new_password" class="" data-error="Please use at least eight characters, one number, one uppercase character and one in lowercase." data-success="That password looks wonderful.">New Password</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">done</i>
  <input id="icon_password_confirmation" type="password" class="validate" required>
  <label for="icon_password_confirmation" class="" data-error="It seems like you made a mistake typing in your password for a second time." data-success="You still remember the password you just typed in. That's great!">Confirm Password</label>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: it works good for me with no issues, I think there is another style overriding Materialize style, can you post your customized css or your html with css if available ?

Comment: There is no custom css, check the code pen. Not sure how you tested, but to replicate the issue enter a value for confirm password, click on passowrd textbox and click back into confirm password.

Answer (score 0):

Update the **js** code as below and check the difference in error overlap.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#icon_new_password, #icon_password_confirmation").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#icon_new_password").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#icon_password_confirmation").val();
if(password == ''){
  $("#icon_new_password").attr( "class", "" );
  $("label[for='icon_new_password']").attr( "class", "" );
  $('.error').text('empty');

}
  if(confirmPassword == ''){
  $("#icon_password_confirmation").attr( "class", "" );
  $("label[for='icon_password_confirmation']").attr( "class", "" );        
          }
    if(password !='' && confirmPassword != '' && password != confirmPassword){
       $("#icon_new_password").attr( "class", "invalid" );
  $("label[for='icon_new_password']").attr( "class", "active" );
        $("#icon_password_confirmation").attr( "class", "invalid" );
  $("label[for='icon_password_confirmation']").attr( "class", "active" );
    }
}
```